# Use github-markdown-css inside existing blog theme

Tags: css, css-selectors, markdown

I want to add a markdown support to my blog. It's build upon a css theme which defines a lot of styles, even for such basic elements as `p`, `h`, etc. I found project [github-markdown-css](https://github.com/sindresorhus/github-markdown-css) and it looks very nice. However, when I added these styles to my blog and then added `markdown-body` class to article's div, the content of the articles didn't look as I expected. Some styles (for example `font-family`) comes from the blog theme.

I've added markdown styles like this:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/styles.css')
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/github-markdown.css')
```

Since `github-markdown.css` is below the `styles.css` I expected that it would have higher priority. Is it possible to somehow clear theme's styles for articles with `markdown-body` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, a solution for me became `:not` [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not). Only articles could have a markdown body in my blog. Each article had an `.article-entry` class around its body. So, I just changed this to `.article-entry:not(.markdown-body)`. Only few lines of css were modified, looks like a pretty elegant solution.